same column names into two tables
I have the same column names "outcomedate" into two separate tables but I want from a specific table, not the other table, but it keeps showing "Ambiguous" error.
please help
SELECT OutcomeDate FROM [HIV].[dbo].[tblTBEpisode] WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT OutcomeDate FROM  [HIV].[dbo].[tblPatient]
 WHERE [HIV].[dbo].[tblTBEpisode].OutcomeDate = [HIV].[dbo].[tblPatient].OutcomeDate);


How about you post the full error message...

You need to fully qualify the column in the select list too:
SELECT [HIV].[dbo].[tblTBEpisode].OutcomeDate
-- Here^
FROM [HIV].[dbo].[tblTBEpisode]
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT [HIV].[dbo].[tblTBEpisode].OutcomeDate
              -- And here, although you could just use * ^
              FROM  [HIV].[dbo].[tblPatient]
              WHERE [HIV].[dbo].[tblTBEpisode].OutcomeDate = 
                    [HIV].[dbo].[tblPatient].OutcomeDate);

